# Symfony 2.3 form is not passing all fields to formView

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am hoping someone can help me debug an issue I am having with form fields not being passed to the form view in Symfony 2.3.

I have a form that I am working on that I built originally a few months ago.  The form worked fine until I decided to add a couple of fields to it.  I added the fields to the Entity and updated the database schema without an issue.  I added the fields to the form type class and then added them to the twig template.

That is where the issue arose, I keep getting an error saying that

```
Method "adminFromEmail" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in SaveAdminBundle:System:systemsettings.html.twig at line 38
```

So I started doing some digging.  I did a `dump()` of the form and got the following response back:

#### `$form` variable dump

```
object(stdClass)#2761 (13) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(27) "Symfony\Component\Form\Form" 
["config"]=> object(stdClass)#2769 (4) { 
    ["__CLASS__"]=> string(34) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder" 
    ["children"]=> string(8) "Array(0)" 
    ["unresolvedChildren"]=> string(8) "Array(0)" 
    ["locked"]=> bool(true) } 
    ["parent"]=> NULL 
    ["children"]=> object(stdClass)#2773 (4) { 
        ["__CLASS__"]=> string(42) "Symfony\Component\Form\Util\OrderedHashMap" 
        ["elements"]=> string(9) "Array(14)" 
        ["orderedKeys"]=> string(9) "Array(14)" 
        ["managedCursors"]=> string(8) "Array(0)" 
    } 
    ["errors"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["submitted"]=> bool(false) 
    ["modelData"]=> object(stdClass)#2774 (17) { 
         ["__CLASS__"]=> string(38) "Save\AdminBundle\Entity\SystemSettings" 
         ["id"]=> int(1) 
         ["loginUrl"]=> string(36) "#######################" 
         ["resetUrl"]=> string(36) "#######################" 
         ["clientLoginUrl"]=> string(36) "####################" 
         ["adminLoginUrl"]=> string(36) "######################" 
         ["adminFromEmail"]=> string(0) ""
         ["adminFromName"]=> string(0) "" 
         ["userRegistrationEmail"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["userRegistrationByAdminEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["userRegistrationByClientEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["clientRegistrationEmail"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["clientRegistrationEmailAdminCopy"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["adminRegistrationEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["loginResetByAdminEmail"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["passwordResetStartEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["passwordResetEndEmail"]=> NULL 
     } 
     ["normData"]=> object(stdClass)#2788 (17) { 
         ["__CLASS__"]=> string(38) "Save\AdminBundle\Entity\SystemSettings" 
         ["id"]=> int(1) 
         ["loginUrl"]=> string(36) "###################" 
         ["resetUrl"]=> string(36) "###################" 
         ["clientLoginUrl"]=> string(36) "##################" 
         ["adminLoginUrl"]=> string(36) "###################" 
         ["adminFromEmail"]=> string(0) "" 
         ["adminFromName"]=> string(0) "" 
         ["userRegistrationEmail"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["userRegistrationByAdminEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["userRegistrationByClientEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["clientRegistrationEmail"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["clientRegistrationEmailAdminCopy"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["adminRegistrationEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["loginResetByAdminEmail"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["passwordResetStartEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["passwordResetEndEmail"]=> NULL 
     } 
     ["viewData"]=> object(stdClass)#2789 (17) { 
         ["__CLASS__"]=> string(38) "Save\AdminBundle\Entity\SystemSettings" 
         ["id"]=> int(1) 
         ["loginUrl"]=> string(36) "#####################" 
         ["resetUrl"]=> string(36) "#####################" 
         ["clientLoginUrl"]=> string(36) "#####################" 
         ["adminLoginUrl"]=> string(36) "#####################" 
         ["adminFromEmail"]=> string(0) "" 
         ["adminFromName"]=> string(0) "" 
         ["userRegistrationEmail"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["userRegistrationByAdminEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["userRegistrationByClientEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["clientRegistrationEmail"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["clientRegistrationEmailAdminCopy"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["adminRegistrationEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["loginResetByAdminEmail"]=> string(57) "Proxies\__CG__\Save\MailMessagesBundle\Entity\MailMessage" 
         ["passwordResetStartEmail"]=> NULL 
         ["passwordResetEndEmail"]=> NULL 
     } 
     ["extraData"]=> array(0) { } 
     ["synchronized"]=> bool(true) 
     ["defaultDataSet"]=> bool(true) 
     ["lockSetData"]=> bool(false) }
```

However, when I did a dump of the view after calling `$form->createView()`, I got this:

#### `$view` variable dump

```
object(stdClass)#2761 (5) { 
     ["__CLASS__"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
     ["vars"]=> array(25) { 
         ["value"]=> string(38) "Save\AdminBundle\Entity\SystemSettings" 
         ["attr"]=> string(8) "Array(0)" 
         ["form"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
         ["id"]=> string(14) "systemsettings" 
         ["name"]=> string(14) "systemsettings" 
         ["full_name"]=> string(14) "systemsettings" 
         ["disabled"]=> bool(false) 
         ["label"]=> NULL 
         ["multipart"]=> bool(false) 
         ["block_prefixes"]=> string(8) "Array(3)" 
         ["unique_block_prefix"]=> string(15) "_systemsettings" 
         ["translation_domain"]=> string(8) "messages" 
         ["cache_key"]=> string(30) "_systemsettings_systemsettings" 
         ["read_only"]=> bool(false) 
         ["errors"]=> string(8) "Array(0)" 
         ["valid"]=> bool(true) 
         ["data"]=> string(38) "Save\AdminBundle\Entity\SystemSettings" 
         ["required"]=> bool(true) 
         ["max_length"]=> NULL 
         ["pattern"]=> NULL 
         ["size"]=> NULL 
         ["label_attr"]=> string(8) "Array(0)" 
         ["compound"]=> bool(true) 
         ["method"]=> string(4) "POST" 
         ["action"]=> string(0) "" 
      } 
      ["parent"]=> NULL 
      ["children"]=> array(15) { 
          ["clientRegistrationEmail"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["adminRegistrationEmail"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["userRegistrationEmail"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["passwordResetStartEmail"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["passwordResetEndEmail"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["loginUrl"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["resetUrl"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["clientRegistrationEmailAdminCopy"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["clientLoginUrl"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView"   
          ["adminLoginUrl"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["userRegistrationByAdminEmail"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["userRegistrationByClientEmail"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView"  
          ["loginResetByAdminEmail"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["updateSettings"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" 
          ["_token"]=> string(31) "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" } 
          ["rendered"]=> bool(false) 
       }
```

If you look closely at the two printouts you can see that `adminFromEmail` and `adminFromName` both show up when dumping the `$form` variable but not after calling `$form->createView()` and I'm not sure why.

I am including the relevant areas of the files associated with this.

#### Form Class:

```
class SystemSettingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        ->add('adminFromEmail', 'text') 
        ->add('adminFromName', 'text')
        ...
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) 
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Save\AdminBuildle\Entity\SystemSettings'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'systemsettings';
    }
}
```

#### The Entity:

```
class SystemSettings
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="system_from_email", type="string", length=100)
     */
     private $adminFromEmail;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="system_from_name", type="string", length=100)
     */
     private $adminFromName;

     ...
 }
```

**Note:** The getters and setters are both properly formed in the Entity ( created by running `doctrine:generate:entities` )

#### The Controller:

```
public function listSystemSettingsAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $system_setting = $em->getRepository('SaveAdminBundle:SystemSettings')->find(1);
    if(is_null($system_setting)){
        $system_setting = new SystemSettings();
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(new SystemSettingsType(), $system_setting);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid() ){
        $em->persist($system_setting);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('SaveAdminBundle:System:systemsettings.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView()));
}
```

#### The Twig Template:

```
...
{% block body %}
<div class="tabbed-box">
    <h1>System Settings</h1>
       <div class="tabbed-area">
           <ul class="tabs">
               <li><a href="#" class="tab active" id="tab_1" title="content_1">System Settings</a></li>
           </ul>
           <div class="content" id="content_1">
               {{ form_start(form) }}
               <fieldset>
                   <legend>System Settings</legend>
                   <ul class="form-fields">

                       ...

                       <li>
                           {{ form_row(form.adminFromEmail) }}                       
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           {{ form_row(form.adminFromName) }}
                       </li>

                       ...

                 </ul>
             </fieldset>
             <div class="button-bar">
                 {{ form_widget(form.updateSettings) }}
             </div>
         {{ form_end(form) }}
     </div>
</div>
...
```

If anyone has an idea as to why the form fields would not be passed on to the form view, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to me that looks like either a clear cache issue or you may be missing a use statement for your entity. The code looks correct to me.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it made me go back and look closer at the file chain to see if I had everything right and I found the problem.  I somehow managed to create 2 identical files SystemSettingType.php and SystemSettingsType.php (notice the extra "s" after "Setting"), I was editing the wrong file but it wasn't until I received your confirmation that the code looked right that I really began scrutinizing it.  I hate stupid mistakes like that.

Comment: meh i've made much worse at least SO is here to help